# Rails many to many association produces error: NoMethodError: undefined method `product' for #<ChoiceProductLink:0x00000106838310>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many-through

I followed this tutorial to add a many to many association:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZJXHmesqJr0&index=35&list=PLvG9ngQqIEISob71DI7Id68lXLQ4hVoVH
```

My goal is to create a products table, a choices table and a connection between these tables (many to many). On those connections I need to store information like price.

This is my code

Schema.rb:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20141213005617) do

    create_table "choice_product_links", force: true do |t|
      t.integer  "price"
      t.datetime "created_at"
      t.datetime "updated_at"
      t.integer  "choice_id"
      t.integer  "product_id"
    end

    create_table "choices", force: true do |t|
      t.string   "name"
      t.decimal  "price"
      t.text     "description"
      t.datetime "created_at"
      t.datetime "updated_at"
    end

    create_table "products", force: true do |t|
      t.string   "name"
      t.datetime "created_at"
      t.datetime "updated_at"
    end

  end
```

Models are:

```
  class Choice < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :choice_product_links
    has_many :products, :through => :choice_product_links
  end


class ChoiceProductLink < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :product
      belongs_to :choice
    end

 class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :choice_product_links
      has_many :choices, :through => :choice_product_links
    end
```

When I use the console to test my code, I enter a product p1 (works fine), a choice c1 (works fine). The problem occurs when I do the following:

```
>> cpl1 = ChoiceProductLink.new
#<ChoiceProductLink id: nil, price: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, choice_id: nil,   product_id: nil>

>> cpl1.save
true

>> cpl1.product = p1
NoMethodError: undefined method `product=' for #<ChoiceProductLink:0x00000101f31bf8>
```

Can somebody help me? 
Thanks guys

Comment: Do I have to use "foreign key"?

Comment: I think you mis-pasted... You put a Youtube link in your question. :-)

Comment: @JoshuaSmock Thats a 5 minutes youtube Tutorial by CodeAcademy how to deals with many to many.
So that link is correct :p

Comment: @JoshuaSmock Can you help me? Or please vote up, because nobidy helps me :p

Comment: @BenSpi To be frank, there's no reason I can see that would cause that error. There's technically nothing stopping you from manually assigning the associations on a join model like you're doing. Joshua is correct in that you don't normally do it this way, but it is technically legal.

Answer (score 1):

My previous answer was wrong -- sorry. I'm not entirely sure why your model isn't working properly. I just set up a test Rails application and ran all of the code you ran with the same migrations and class structure, and got these results:

```
Joshuas-MacBook-Pro:models joshua$ rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 4.0.0)
irb(main):001:0> cpl1 = ChoiceProductLink.new
=> #<ChoiceProductLink id: nil, price: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, choice_id: nil, product_id: nil>
irb(main):002:0> cpl1.save
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (7.0ms)  INSERT INTO "choice_product_links" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", Sat, 13 Dec 2014 03:12:50 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Sat, 13 Dec 2014 03:12:50 UTC +00:00]]
   (0.7ms)  commit transaction
=> true
irb(main):004:0* p1 = Product.new
=> #<Product id: nil, name: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):005:0> p1.save
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (1.5ms)  INSERT INTO "products" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", Sat, 13 Dec 2014 03:13:25 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Sat, 13 Dec 2014 03:13:25 UTC +00:00]]
   (2.5ms)  commit transaction
=> true
irb(main):006:0> cpl1.product = p1
=> #<Product id: 1, name: nil, created_at: "2014-12-13 03:13:25", updated_at: "2014-12-13 03:13:25">
irb(main):007:0> cpl1.save
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.7ms)  UPDATE "choice_product_links" SET "product_id" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "choice_product_links"."id" = 1  [["product_id", 1], ["updated_at", Sat, 13 Dec 2014 03:13:35 UTC +00:00]]
   (1.6ms)  commit transaction
=> true
```

Is this similar to what you did? As far as I can tell it works...

Comment: I'm afraid that's incorrect; the `belongs_to :product` implicitly creates a `product=` method. Rails doesn't "know" this is a join model, its no different than any other active record model.

Comment: @PaulRichter What do you think is wring with my code?

Comment: @PaulRichter oh, oops, you're right, I misunderstood the question and am also a little rusty with my Rails-foo...

Comment: @JoshuaSmock Thanks a lot for your help!
See my answer that solved the problem. Do you have an idea what I did wring?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is that I create a migration file that contains the following code:

```
class CreateConstraints2 < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end

    create_table :choices do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end

    create_table : choice_product_links do |t|
      t.belongs_to :product
      t.belongs_to :choice
      t.datetime : choice_product_links
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

With that migration file everything works perfectly. What I did before was that I created the tables with separate migration files and added the "has_many" and "belongs_to" later.

I dont know why thats different, but that's the solution. I tried almost 100 times back and forth :p

Comment: I'm confused as heck. So you had separate migration files creating the tables before. Did those migration files create the correct `product_id` and `choice_id` columns?

Comment: @PaulRichter Maybe that's my mistake: I created a table ChoiceProductLink with the two columns: product_id and choice_id hardcoded.
I thought due to name conventions rails will create the required methods. But it looks like it doesn't
Please don't kill me now, if that's a extremely stupid mistake :)

Comment: I don't think that should matter, because the migrations that Rails created (and what showed up in `schema.rb` in your OP) were valid, and the associations are set up using the models rather than the migrations. I copied verbatim what you posted and ran a migration when I tested. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Ok, so that relates to what I was saying in the comment on Joshua's answer. Its not the column names that *create the required methods*, its the `belongs_to` and `has_many` in the models. You are correct that the columns must conform to a naming convention, which in your case is exactly correct.

Comment: Also, this is very important, for clarity: those methods, such as `product=`, and such, don't actually "exist". When you call those methods, rails dynamically "creates" (that's not quite the truth but I'll use that for simplicity) the method on the fly, and sets or returns the value of that column (or performs a SELECT...whatever it needs to do). That's why you need to have the `belongs_to` and such; because Rails uses that to determine whether you're trying to call an association method, and which column(s) and attributes it should be looking at, etc.

Comment: okay, at least now I know how to get it to work. Even though there is a "right" order to do things. Weird, but anyway. Thanks for your great support, guys!

Comment: There's absolutely no "right" order, technically speaking. You can do everything completely out of order, and it'll still work, so long as you have set up all the names and such correctly. Frankly, I don't know why your change work, but I suspect you may have unintentionally had some kind of inconsistent state that your change fixed (because it essentially caused everything to "reboot").

Comment: When it doubt, raze the earth and start over! (This is not serious advice)